# Simple design for storing Enum double[] String triple

Tags: java, tuples

Hiho,

in my app I get at some time a triple of an Enum, a double[] array and a String. The meanig is: there are different "classes" of values (enum-type), the values itself (double[]) and a subclass(String), more like an alias. Each class/type can have several values with different aliases. (But the same values can only have one alias).

My first attempt was a

```
Map<Enum,List<double[]>
```

but I cant fit the alias in there. I now see two possibilities: Use a multimap somehow or introduce a new class. The last one I like to avoid, only for personal reasons. What other ways are there to store this triple in the given manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Map<Enum,Map<String,double[]>>
```

this would fit if an enum type can have multiple alias strings - value list combinations assigned to it.

Answer (score 2):

Make a class to encapsulate the relationship.

```
public class Relationship
{
    private final String theAlias;
    private final double[] theDoubles;
    private final your.blah.Enum theEnum;

    public Relationship(
        final String theAlias,
        final double[] theDoubles,
        final your.blah.Enum theEnum)
    {
        this.theAlias = theAlias;
        this.theDoubles = theDoubles;
        this.theEnum = theEnum;
    }

    ... blah getters ...
}

Map<keyType, Relationship> yourMap;
```

keyType is either String or your.blah.Enum depending on how you want to access the relationship object.

Comment: this might be the better approach, but as I said I don't want to create a new class for it.